# Conditional redirect based on referring source?

Tags: redirects

Is it possible to redirect all traffic from a certain referring URL to a specific page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from a technical point of view, it is possible to examine the referrer URL and issue a redirect if it matches.

Whoever is linking into your site may not like this.  Presumably, they want their users to see some of your content and have linked to where they think is appropriate.  You could certainly do this to correct their mistake or broken link.  I wouldn't do this for traffic from a search engine though.

Comment: Thanks, it an advertiser that linked to the wrong page (homepage instead of specific landing page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}** or **RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}** to set such redirects.

Try something like:

```
#A.B.C.D is the referrer IP@
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^A\.B\.C\.D
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/landingpage.html [NC,L,U,QSA]
```